# how to not hardcode list item name in R?

Tags: r, list

im pretty new to R, i wonder how can do something like the following:

```
a = 'vol'
b = list(a=c(1,2,3))
```

actual output:

```
> b
$a
[1] 1 2 3
```

the output that I wish to have:

```
> b
$vol
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: `stats::setNames` or just `names(b) <- a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Mid-definition

```r
a = 'vol'
b = setNames(list(c(1,2,3)), a)
b
# $vol
# [1] 1 2 3
```

The `list(.)` can have names if you like, they will be overwritten. For instance, this produces the same result: `setNames(list(a=c(1,2,3)), a)` (the initial name `a=` is moot, and has nothing to do with the `a` referenced as the second argument to `setNames`).

#### Post-definition

```r
a = 'vol'
b = list(a=c(1,2,3))
names(b) <- a
b
# $vol
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `lst` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
lst(!! a := c(1, 2, 3))
$vol
[1] 1 2 3
```